# Netbeans 8.2 no tiene la opción de creacion de projectos Java

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

Hoy tomé la decisión de instalar NetBeans IDE 8.2, he visto varios tutoriales y seguí las intrucciones al pie de la letra.
La cuestión es que al intentar crear un nuevo projecto me sale esto así [image: Desconcertado la verdad]

### Intentos

- Descargué e instalé netbeans desde la pagina y actualice mi version de JRE.
- Ya cambie el `netbeans.conf`

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Dices que instalaste netbeans desde la página. ¿Desde qué página? Entiendo que de esta: https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.2/rc/ De ahí, ¿qué bundle te bajaste? ¿Qué cambiaste en el netbeans.conf? Una instalación básica no necesita ningún cambio en ese fichero. ¿Miraste en Tools -> Plugins si tienes instalado Java SE, Base IDE, etc?.

Comment: Hola, descargue el netbeans en esta pagina https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Del netbeans.conf cambie el _jdkhome (ahora lo tengo como: netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111")

Te parece buena idea desinstalar el que ya descargué y bajarme un bundle desde esa pagina que linkeaste?

Saludos!

Comment: Hola, Martin. Bienvenidx a SOes. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta para añadir información usando el enlace **Editar** que está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas. Evita responder en los comentarios :)  Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Yo siempre me lo he instalado desde esa página y no me ha dado ningún problema, ni he tenido que editar ningún fichero de configuración.

Answer (score 1):

se debe a una funcionalidad relativamente reciente de desactivar un grupo de módulos.

Para activarlos ve a `Tools > Plugins` y allí Debes activar el grupo de módulos Java SE

[image: Debes activar el grupo de módulos Java SE]

Por defecto algunos plugins de varios lenguajes vienen deshabilitados para ahorrar la memoria que usa el IDE que de por sí ya es bastante.

### ¿Y si no aparece el grupo Java SE?

Ve a `Tools > Plugins > Settings` y allí agrega el repositorio de módulos, por ejemplo para netbeans 8.2 se agrega:

http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz